# How can I iterate text from a character to another character using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, url, text

Given a url as following :

`https://website.com/demo?name=helloworld&timestamp=1234567890`

How can I iterate from the `=` sign and the `&` sign, resulting in `helloworld` in JS?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Though you don't need to iterate here. You can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) here to get a part of a string

```js
const str = "https://website.com/demo?name=helloworld&timestamp=1234567890";
const start = str.indexOf("=");
const end = str.indexOf("&");

const result = str.slice(start + 1, end);
console.log(result);
```

**2)** If you still want to iterate over from `=` and upto `&` then you can do

```js
const str = "https://website.com/demo?name=helloworld&timestamp=1234567890";
const end = str.indexOf("&");

const resultArr = [];
for (let start = str.indexOf("=") + 1; start < end; ++start) {
  resultArr.push(str[start]);
}

console.log(resultArr.join(""));
```

**3)** You can also use regex here

```
(?<==)\w+
```

```js
const str = "https://website.com/demo?name=helloworld&timestamp=1234567890";
const match = str.match(/(?<==)\w+/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Important note: You can apply this method if you are sure that there is only one "=" and "&" and the text that you want is between them. If that is not the case you will have to search the whole string.

Explanation:
str.indexOf('=') + 1   // will result 30

str.indexOf('&') // will result 40

So, str.slice(30, 40) will give the substring from 30th position to 39th position, it will ignore the 40th position.

```js
let str = 'https://website.com/demo?name=helloworld&timestamp=1234567890'


//1. Find the index of "=" + 1, because slice selects the starting argument.

let subStr = str.slice(str.indexOf('=') + 1, str.indexOf('&'))

console.log(subStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilise regex to figure that out,

```js
const extractStringBetween = (char1,char2) => (str) => str.match(RegExp(`${char1}([^${char1}${char2}]+)${char2}`))[1]

console.log(extractStringBetween('=','&')('https://website.com/demo?name=helloworld&timestamp=1234567890'))
```

This uses group capture.

You can learn more at https://regexr.com/